# R foreach loop runs out of memory in HPC environment

Tags: r, memory, hpc, r-raster, parallel-foreach

I am using the foreach package in R to process raster files.

The R code below works fine locally (on Windows) when adapted to an 8-core processor, but runs out of memory in a HPC environment with 48 cores. The HPC environment has much more memory available (2 TB across all 48 cores) compared with my local box (32 GB), so that's not the limiting factor.

The memory creep occurs as the foreach loop proceeds. It's slow, but enough to eventually run out of memory.

I have tried switching parallel packages (to `doMC`, `doSNOW`), adding numerous garbage collection calls and `rm()` of large objects at the end of every iteration, fiddling with the number of cores used, as well as removing any temporary files immediately.

Any ideas on what may be causing my memory issues?

```
# Set Java memory maximum
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx39g")

library(sp)
library(raster)
library(dismo)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(rgdal)
library(rJava)

# Set directories  
relPath <- "E:/BIEN_Cactaceae/"
bufferDir <- "Data/Buffers"
climDir <- "Data/FutureClimate/"
outDir <- "Analyses/FutureRanges/"
modelDir <- "Analyses/MaxEnt/"
outfileDir <- "OutFiles/"
tempDir <- "E:/Tmp/"

# Set directory for raster temporary files
rasterOptions(tmpdir = tempDir)

# Search for models
models <- list.files(path = paste0(relPath, modelDir), pattern = "rda$")

# Set up cluster
cl <- makeCluster(48, type = "FORK", outfile = paste0(relPath, outfileDir, "predictFuture.txt"))
registerDoParallel(cl)

# Loop through species and predict current ranges
foreach(i = 1:length(models),
        .packages = c("sp", "raster", "dismo", "rgdal", "rJava"),
        .inorder = F) %dopar% {
  # Get taxon
  taxon <- strsplit(models[i], ".", fixed = T)[[1]][1]
  # Get buffer
  tmpBuffer <- readOGR(dsn = paste0(relPath, bufferDir), layer = paste0(taxon, "_buff"), verbose = F)
  # Get scenarios
  scenarios <- list.files(path = paste0(relPath, climDir), pattern = "tif$")
  # Get model
  load(paste0(relPath, modelDir, models[i]))
  # Loop over scenarios
  for (j in scenarios) {
    # Get scenario name
    tmpScenarioName <- strsplit(j, ".", fixed = T)[[1]][1]
    # Skip scenario if already processed
    if (!file.exists(paste0(relPath, outDir, taxon, "_", tmpScenarioName, ".tif"))) {
      # Read, crop, mask predictors
      print(paste0(taxon, " - ", tmpScenarioName, ": processing"))
      tmpScenarioStack <- raster::stack(paste0(relPath, climDir, j))
      preds <- raster::crop(tmpScenarioStack, tmpBuffer)
      preds <- raster::mask(preds, tmpBuffer)
      # Rename predictors
      tmpNames <- paste0(taxon, ".", 1:20)
      tmpNames <- gsub("-", ".", tmpNames, fixed = T)
      tmpNames <- gsub(" ", "_", tmpNames, fixed = T)
      names(preds) <- tmpNames
      # Predict with model
      prediction <- dismo::predict(model_all, preds, progress = "")
      # Export predictions
      writeRaster(prediction, paste0(relPath, outDir, taxon, "_", tmpScenarioName, ".tif"))
      removeTmpFiles(h = 2)
    }
  }
}

stopCluster(cl)
```